# Why doesn't my program work with large files(650M) correctly? K&R exersice 5-13 tail

Tags: arrays, c, string, large-files

> Exercise 5-13. Write the program tail, which prints the last n lines
> of its input. By default, n is set to 10, let us say, but it can be
> changed by an optional argument so that "tail -n" prints the last n
> lines. The program should behave rationally  no matter how
> unreasonable the input or the value of n. Write the program so it
> makes the best use of available storage;  lines should be stored as in
> the sorting program of Section 5.6,  not in a two-dimensional array of
> fixed size.

The code I've written(I've put it at the end of the post) works fine with small files, but it gives weird outputs when it's a large file. The file is about 650 megabytes, each line is well over 1000 characters, except for the last 11 lines which are : 1, 2, 3, to 11. When I run it with -11, everything works fine with this output:

```
Printing 11 lines
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

But when I run it with -1, I get this output:

```
Printing 1 line
input too big too handle
```

Unlike with -11, which takes about 5 or 6 seconds to run this one runs pretty fast meaning the error happens too early in the program. Same output as in -1 with -2, -3 and -4.
At -5 I get this:

```
Printing 5 lines
1
8
9
10
11
```

with -6 this:

```
Printing 6 lines
1
7
8
9
10
11
```

It works correctly with -7 and above:

```
Printing 7 lines
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

If I remove the last line, 11, and run it with -5 or -6 I get this output:

```
Printing 5 lines

7
8
9
10
```

and

```
Printing 6 lines

6
7
8
9
10
```

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int isint(char s[]); 
int toint(char s[]); /* convert s to an integer */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int no); /* read the last 'no' lines and save them in lineptr */
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int no);

#define MAXLINE 100 /* the maximum acceptable number of lines to be printed */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 10;
    char *lineptr[MAXLINE];

    while (--argc > 0) {
        if ((*++argv)[0] == '-' && isint(*argv) && toint(*argv) <= MAXLINE) {
            n = toint(*argv);
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("invalid argument %s\n", *argv);
    }

    printf("Printing %d line%s\n", n, n > 1 ? "s" : "");
    if (readlines(lineptr, n) >= 0) {
        writelines(lineptr, n);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("input too big too handle\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int isint(char s[])
{
    while (*s == '-' || *s == '0')
        s++;
    if (isdigit(*s)) {
        while (*s != '\0')
            if (!isdigit(*s++))
                return 0;
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

int toint(char s[])
{
    while (*s == '-' || *s == '0')
        s++;
    return atoi(s);
}

#define MAXLEN 1000 /* maximum acceptable length of a line to be saved */

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int no)
{
    char *alloc(int n, int no);
    int get_line(char *, int); /* returns the length of a line excluding '\0' */
    void push(char *lineptr[], char *p, int len); /* pushes a pointer in lineptr */

    int len, i;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];

    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        lineptr[i] = NULL;  /* in case the number of to-be-printed lines is less thatn 'no' */

    while ((len = get_line(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if ((p = alloc(len, no)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            line[len-1] = '\0'; /* remove the nl character, -*/
                                /*-the last line of input is expected to end in a nl */
            strcpy(p, line);
            push(lineptr, p, no);
        }
    return 1;
}

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int no)
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        if (lineptr[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", lineptr[i]);
}

int get_line(char *line, int lim)
{
    int i, c;

    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        line[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        line[i++] = c;
    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

void push(char *lineptr[], char *p, int no)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < no-1; i++)
        lineptr[i] = lineptr[i+1];
    lineptr[no-1] = p;
}

#define ALLOCSIZE MAXLINE * MAXLEN

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static int allocn = 0; /* the number of allocations */
static char *allocp = allocbuf;
static char *leftalloc = allocbuf; /* left edge of the replaceable section of array */
static char *rightalloc = allocbuf - 1; /* right edge of the replaceable section of array */

char *alloc(int n, int no)
{
    int i;
    char *j;

    if (allocn%no == no - 1) {
        leftalloc = allocbuf;
        rightalloc = allocbuf - 1; /* no line is replaceable yet */
    }
    if (allocn >= no) {
        while (allocn-no >= no) /* reduce allocn to congruent modulo 'no' value to prevent overflow */
            allocn -= no;
        for (i = 0; i < allocn%no; i++)
            while (*rightalloc++ != '\0');
                ;
    }

    if (n <= rightalloc - leftalloc + 1) {
        leftalloc += n;
        allocn++;
        return leftalloc - n;
    } else if (n <= allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp) {
        allocp += n;
        allocn++;
        return allocp - n;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

I checked, the problem is most likely from the alloc function

Comment: Something for you to think about:  how many lines are in these large files?

Comment: In get_line you do not test the max line length. Check also for the value of i in each line affectation.

Comment: Did you try to debug the `readlines` function? I suggest you learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 254380 (11 numbers as the last lines)

Comment: @PtitXav (--lim > 0) insures that i doesn't go past the limit.

Comment: I checked, the problem is from the alloc function because when I replace it with a 2d array everything works but that’s not how the book wants me tos tore data so if anyone could help with that, I’d be thankful